# How to add user specified items to OPC data group

Tags: matlab, tags, matlab-guide, popupmenu, opc

I am creating a MATLAB application which connects to an OPC Server and reads the Tag properties. The MATLAB documentation is telling me that I can add a group, add tag items, and then read the value:

```
grp = addgroup(da, 'ExRead');
itm = additem(grp, 'Tag.Argument');
```

The problem is that I don't know the tag argument, in my app the user is selecting an available tag in a popupmenu and the value is written to a string, but when I call:

```
val = get(handles.popupmenu1, 'Value'); // Ask for Value selected item
string_val = get(handles.popupmenu1, 'String'); // Ask for string
stringName = string_val{val}; // Ask for string corresponding to the specified value 
set(handles.text1, 'String', stringName); // Display the selected tag
item1 = additem(Group1, stringName); // Add the selected string to a global group "Group1"
read1 = read(Group1, item1); // Read the value
set(handles.text11, 'String', read1); // Display the value
```

But when I run the code MATLAB generates errors. I guess the problem is `item1 = additem(Group1, stringName);` In all the MATLAB documentation examples I see something like `item1 = additem(Group1, 'adres.adres.1');` This should explain why I am unable to add any data to the `Group1`.

But how can I add an item to a taggroup which must be specified/selected by a user?

Answer (score 0):

`Group1` appears to be a variable here, that is undefined. Perhaps you meant to type `'Group1'`, with quotes? That would add `item` to a group called `Group1`.

Comment: I solved the "Group 1 unspecified" -error. Matlab syntax requires that also global variables must be declared in every scope. But I still can't get the tag properties to display in the "text11" textbox.

Comment: Is the tag property a number? If it is, you would probably want `set(handles.text11, 'String', num2str(read1));`

Comment: No it isn't a number. I guess the problem is    item1 = additem(Group1, stringName); 

In all the Matlab documentation examples I see something like   item1 = additem(Group1, 'adres.adres.1'); 

This should explain why I am unable to add any data to the    Group1

But how to add a item to a taggroup wich must be specified by a user? I will add all of above to the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you don't know which tag names you should use.

The correct ItemID (Tag name) is typically found by browsing the server address space.

Before you implement browsing in your application (if possible with MATLAB), you can use test clients, such as [Prosys OPC Client](https://www.prosysopc.com/products/opc-client/) to browse the address space and find the proper ItemID(s) to use.